# form submit browsers combatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new in programming. I use following code to submit a form:

```
     <form action="" method="post"  class="label" id="form1">

     <span id="sprytextfield1">
    <label>Ονομα*
      <br />
      <input name="onoma" type="text" id="onoma" size="30" />
    </label>
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield2">

    <label>Επίθετο*
      <br />
      <input name="surname" type="text" id="epitheto" size="30" />
    </label>
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield3">

      <label>Τηλέφωνο*<br />
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="tilefono" size="25" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"> </span></label>
</span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield4">

    <label>email*<br />
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" />
    </label>
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield5">

      <label>username*
        <br />
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30" />
      </label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span></p>
    <p><span id="sprypassword1">

    <label>password*<br />
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </label>
    <span class="passwordRequiredMsg"></span></span></p>
    <p>

      <label>Εδρα-Νομός*
        <select name="Edra_nomos" size="1" id="edranomos">
        <option value=" Επιλογές"> Επιλογές</option>
  ......................................................... 

          </select>
      </label>
      </p>
    <p>

    <label>Εδρα-Πόλη*
        <select name="Edra-Poli" id="edrapoli">
        </select>
      </label>

     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

         $('#edranomos').change(function(){
             $('#edrapoli').empty();

     var option = '';
     var edra = [
     .................................................................

     ];

     var s = $( "#edranomos option:selected" ).text().trim();   

     for(n=0;n<edra.length;n++){
         if(s==edra[n][0]){         
             for(i=1;i<edra[n].length;i++){
             option += '<option value="'+ edra[n][i] + '">' + edra[n][i] + '</option>';          
             }
             $('#edrapoli').append(option);         
             }                   
         }
      });
     });
     </script></p>
    <p>         

      <label>Είδος Μεταφοράς*
        <select name="Eidos_metaforas" size="1" id="eidosmetaforas">        
         ...........................................................        

          </select>
      </label>
      </p>
    <label>Υπηρεσίες*

      <select name="ypiresies" size="3" multiple="multiple" id="exeidikypiresies">
       .....................................................

    </select>
    </label>
    <p><br />
  </p>
    <p>
      <input name="Submit"  type="submit"  id="button" value="Εγγραφή" />
  </p>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>





<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#form1").submit(function() {     

        alert($('#onoma').val());
        alert($('#epitheto').val());
        alert($('#email').val());
        alert($('#tilefono').val());
        alert($('#username').val());
        alert($('#password').val());
        alert($('#edranomos').val());
        alert($('#edrapoli').val());
        alert($('#eidosmetaforas').val());
        if($('#exeidikypiresies').val()!=null){
        var e = $('#exeidikypiresies').val().toString();
        } else {
            var e = 'nothing';
            }
        alert(e);

        $.ajax({
  url: 'php/register.php',   
  type: 'POST',
  data: { onoma:$('#onoma').val() , epitheto:$('#epitheto').val() , 
  email:$('#email').val() , tilefono:$('#tilefono').val(),
  username:$('#username').val() , password:$('#password').val() ,
  edranomos:$('#edranomos').val() , edrapoli:$('#edrapoli').val(),
  eidosmetaforas:$('#eidosmetaforas').val() , exeidikypiresies:e},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response){        
      alert(response['message']);  
      if(response['success']=='1'){
          window.location = 'http://www.transergo.com/index.php';   
          }

}
});
});
});
</script>
```

My problem is that code doesn't work with firefox ( i can't even store data to database), half-works with chrome  ( doesn't show alert box on response) and it works perfectly with IE , so its obviously a browsers compatibility issue. I have no idea what to look for. Found nothing specific by googling. Any idea;

I UPDATED CODE

Comment: what is the error in your console?

Comment: Simply,using firefox it returns my page html code

Comment: Try to serialize form and then post data. like data:$('#form1').serialize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below return statement after ajax call so that form direct submit will not happen.

```
return false;
```

Also better avoid alert statements for debugging.
You can print them in console with

```
console.log("test");
```

Comment: Adding "return false" leads to success. Thanks jeevanragula

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the HTML in your page, but I assume it is because you are making an AJAX call when you are trying to POST the form. This is an issue since $.ajax is asynchronous, so your page is probably reloading/navigating away prior to you getting results back from the $.ajax call.

Comment: Do you suggest not using AJAX; I use it relying on several stack overflow topics..

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the AJAX call, without seeing the entire page to get an idea of what you are doing it is hard to tell.

If you need to make the AJAX call first, maybe you should use a function to make the AJAX call and on success submit the form rather than making the call on the "submit" event.

Comment: I try simply to store some data in my database. And i updated my code

Comment: You are posting your form via the submit button, once the ajax call is made it does not wait since it is asynchronous so you page is refreshed before the ajax call can return.

Why aren't you just posting the form to the "php/register.php"?